# Wrong Record Type set in Apex Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, record-type

I'm writing a test for my custom controller of a visualforce page.

```
private static Account createAcc()
{
    Account acc = new Account();

    acc.Name = 'TEST DSI DELETE MC';
    acc.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('AnnonceurClient').getRecordTypeId();
    acc.StatutCompte__c = 'ClientActif';
    acc.CodePostal__c = '10000';
    acc.Ville__c = 'TOTO';
    acc.NumeroComptable__c = null;

    insert acc;
    return acc;
}

private static ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c createMediaCampaignComm(Account acc)
{
    System.debug('Create Test Media Campaign Comm');

    ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c mc2 = new ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c();

    mc2.Name = 'TEST DSI DELETE MC Comm';
    mc2.ADvendio__Account__c = acc.Id;
    mc2.ADvendio__invoice_recipient__c = acc.Id;
    mc2.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('C_3_Commande').getRecordTypeId();
    mc2.ADvendio__Stage__c = 'Commande';

    insert mc2;
    return mc2;
}

@isTest
public static void testCommande()
{
    // Création des données de test
    Account acc = ConfirmMediaCampaignDeleteExtTest.createAcc();
    ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c mc_comm = ConfirmMediaCampaignDeleteExtTest.createMediaCampaignComm(acc);

    Test.startTest();

    // Vérification des données de test
    System.assert(acc != null && acc.Id != null, 'Le compte de test n\'a pas été créé');
    System.assert(mc_comm != null && mc_comm.Id != null, 'La Media Campaign Commande n\'a pas été créée');

    System.debug([SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c WHERE Id = :mc_comm.Id]);

    // Test Commande
    // Création de la page VF et assignation à la campagne Commande
    PageReference vf_page1 = Page.ConfirmMediaCampaignDelete;
    vf_page1.getParameters().put('Id', mc_comm.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(vf_page1);

    // Appel suppression du Controller
    ApexPages.StandardController sc1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(mc_comm);
    ConfirmMediaCampaignDeleteExt ext1 = new ConfirmMediaCampaignDeleteExt(sc1);
    ext1.confirmDeletion();

    // Vérification que la commande n'a pas été supprimée
    List<ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c> mc_comm_l = [SELECT Id, isDeleted FROM ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c WHERE Id = :mc_comm.Id ALL ROWS];
    System.debug(mc_comm_l[0]);
    System.assertEquals(
        mc_comm_l[0].IsDeleted,
        false,
        'L\'attribut isDeleted de la MC Commande est vrai, la campagne a été supprimée alors qu\'elle ne devrait pas l\'être'
    );

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

The first two asserts checking if the account and media campaign exists are OK.
But then the System.debug printing the record type of my variable mc_comm shows the record type is wrong: the record type is different than the one I just set in my createMediaCampaignComm function.
So then my test fails because the record is deleted whereas it should not (deletion autorized based on record type developer name).

How is it possible ?

Comment: do you have automation (flow, PB, other triggers) on `ADvendio__MediaCampaign__c` that swaps the recordTYpeId?